# How to set up an environment to write/test Clarity smart contracts within a Django project

Tags: development-environment, clarity, clarity-lang, stacks-blockchain

I'm setting up a web project that can (i) interact with the Stacks blockchain and (ii) deploy/interact with Clarity smart contracts.

I need help in configuring the environment correctly. Following is how I typically setup web projects.

---

I typically use python's Django framework. Moreover, I create a Javascript pipeline as a standalone, separate environment inside the Django project.

I do that via initializing a new `npm` project in the root of the Django project, and thereafter installing a bundler like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/). I.e.:

```
npm init -y
npm install webpack webpack-cli --save-dev
```

This creates the `package.json` and `package-lock.json` files, as well as a `node_modules` folder where JavaScript library dependencies reside.

Next, I create a `webpack.config.js` file at the root of the Django project. I add an [npm script](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/scripts) target in `package.json` to run `webpack`. I can then run `npm run dev` to execute the webpack script. This essentially sets up my Javascript pipeline, giving me a `bundle` file I can use with Django's templates.

That's it.

In short, if I want to use any external JS library, I can simply install it via `npm`, regenerate the `webpack bundle` file via `npm run dev`, and use the bundle in my Django templates.

This approach is quite flexible - I can even set up `React` (with the `Babel` compiler) within the Django project if need be.

---

My goal is to start testing Clarity code within this sort of a set up. I've already seen the basic documentation regarding testing Clarity code here: https://docs.stacks.co/docs/write-smart-contracts/

But that does not help one understand how to use Clarity code within a production-grade setup (of the sort I described above).

If you have experience regarding setting this up, please provide an illustrative example. Thanks in advance.